# How can i insert term in a specific language of Polylang?

Tags: categories, taxonomy, terms

I have created a plug-in which permits to create a category with slugs.

There is the code :

```
wp_insert_term(
    'Cat1',
    'category',
    array(
    'slug' => 'slug-cat1',
));

wp_insert_term(
'Agenda',
'category',
array(
'slug' => 'slug-agenda',
'parent'=> term_exists( 'Cat1', 'category' )['term_id']

));
```

It permits to create my category in the default language of the website. So my question is, do you know how can i create a category as before, but i want to create it in another language than the default. I'm using Polylang to translate my website.

Have a good day.

Answer (score 2):

You can actually make it this way:

```
$cat1 = wp_insert_term(
  'Cat1',
  'category',
  ['slug' => 'slug-cat1'],
);

$agenda = wp_insert_term(
  'Agenda',
  'category',
  [
    'slug' => 'slug-agenda',
    'parent'=> term_exists( 'Cat1', 'category' )['term_id'],
  ],
);

pll_set_term_language($cat1['term_id'], 'fr');
pll_set_term_language($agenda['term_id'], 'de');
```

Here is link to Polylang Function reference:
https://polylang.wordpress.com/documentation/documentation-for-developers/functions-reference/

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately, you need to buy the pro-version of Polylang. This is a feature, which the pro-version of the plugin provides for custom post types.

That is one of the tricks, which make people buy the pro-version.

I think Polylang pro-version starts at 99,- € (depending on your needs).

In comparison: WPML has the same features (and more) with only 79,- € I think.
I have recently encountered the same problem and the cheapeast solution, was to buy the pro of WPML.

I know the answer might be not satisfying, but that's how it currently is.

Comment: Thanks for your answer then, i understand now why people are buying pro-version. Have a nice day

Comment: I will buy it. Do you know what i have to do then for my request ?

Comment: I can only tell about WPML, that is the solution that I've purchased. There should be options in the plugin which will let you do that: Special hint: browse the documentation of Polylang ;-)

Comment: Hi @user3135691 , i found that Polylang can use the WPML API. Maybe i can use your solution ?

Comment: @Tweak, that doesn't make very much sense from my perspective. You don't buy the pro version of WPML just to fiddle some Polylang solution to it. Doh! Stick to one side - like the a Jedi. Either the dark side or not.. Polylang or WPML.

Comment: Hi @user3135691 , we can do it with the free version of Polylang. :)